# db_select with condition on json blob column in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, drupal-10

I have a json blob column with data listed below in postgreSQL,column name is **data**, for building a chart in drupal10 website. i have to use db_select to get data based on a condtion in json key named  **chart_title**

> [   {
> "to": "Joint Programme",
> "nid": 20073,
> "from": "Funds Mobilized",
> "value": 272172483,
> "status": true,
> "weight": 5.8,
> "api_uri": "http://example.com",
> "to_color": "#b6ada7",
> "timestamp": 1708075222,
> "chart_type": "bar",
> "embed_code": "
>
> google
>
> ",
> "from_color": "#f78f20",
> "line_color": "#f78f20",
> "sort_order": 0,
> "chart_group": "Resources 2022",
> "chart_title": "By Data",
> "chart_collection": "Investments"   },

i have tried this

```html
$connection = \Drupal::database();
$result = $connection->select('chart_data', 't')
    ->fields('t', ['data'])
    ->condition('t.data', 'By Data', '=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();
```

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug your code?